# Dynamically Expand Collapsible Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I want to expand the collapsible content of a jQuery Mobile collapsible content section. I know I can click the heading to expand it, but I don't want to rely on the user to click the same section every time the page refreshes. I know I can set a variable in the html, but that won't do because the collapsible content will still close on postback.

I need this to be done with code rather than by the user. You can see my failed attempt below. I used the template from VS 2013's Web Forms project as a start then I added jQuery Mobile and followed the instructions from jQuery Mobile's [site](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/content/content-collapsible-methods.html), or so I thought. This is a simplified test page but ultimately, I want to have an ASP.NET variables to detect whether, on postback, a section has already been clicked and if a collapsible section has already been clicked, open it again so the user doesn't have to click the same place again. Is there any way to persist the expanded state or dynamically expand jQuery Mobile's collapsible content?

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="ExpandTest._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <script>
        $(".myDiv").trigger("expand");
    </script>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
        <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
        <p><a href="http://www.asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="myDiv" data-role="collapsible">
            <h2>Getting Started</h2>
            <p>ASP.NET Web Forms lets you build dynamic websites using a familiar drag-and-drop, event-driven model. A design surface and hundreds of controls and components let you rapidly build sophisticated, powerful UI-driven sites with data access.
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301948">Learn more &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

-- EDIT --
Thing I have tried (even just for proof of concept) that fail:

```
$(".myDiv").trigger('expand'); // Apparently does not execute
$('.myDiv').on("click", alert("Fe Fi Foo Bar!");); // does not run anything within
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
```

Also, I have recently read that `document.ready` is supposed to be used for jQuery but [not jQuery Mobile](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html). Telling is the fact that I cannot use the same code that other user seem to think works and the same code that works in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6txWy/) already. This leads me to believe I'm missing something that should be obvious. I have modified the order of loading jQuery Mobile in relation to the code to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `data-collapsed="false"` attribute in collapsible div? If you're using JQM 1.4 `$(".selector").collapsible("expand");`.

Comment: `data-collapsed="false"` keeps the same set open regardless of weather or not I want it to be open, i.e. it is not dynamic. I'm using JQM 1.4 and `$(".myDiv").collapsible("expand");` does not work that way I'm using it somehow.

Comment: @Omar If `$(".myDiv").collapsible("expand");` works in any way for you I would like to know when and where you load JQM and when and where you load the custom script?

Comment: I added `<a id="btn" href="#" data-role="button"> Open / close menus </a>` and ` $("#btn").bind("click", function (event) {
            $("h2.ui-collapsible-heading").trigger("click");
        });` and that does trigger a click. Now I just need to trigger an expand event on `pageinit`.

Comment: Use `pagecontainbeforeshow` instead of `pageinit`. `$("#col_id").collapsible("expand");`.

Comment: @Omar Maybe you can suggest a block of code? I tried this w/o it working: `$(document).on("pagecontainbeforeshow", "#page", function () {
                alert("Look at the bar foo!");
                $("h2.ui-collapsible-heading").trigger("click");
            });`

Comment: You can't bind pageContainer events to specific pages unfortunately, that's why it's not working.  Remove `#page` from code and try again.

Comment: @Omar I removed "#page" and still no success. I have a hack that works on Android. Basically I execute a click event on h3 of an expandable panel. I know this will lead to problems in the future but I don't have a better solution now.

Comment: I'm just surprised why it isn't working. Do you have a live link?

Answer (score 1):

Add an ASP.Net hidden field to the page with viewstate enabled.

The jQM collapsible has events for expand and collapse.  On the client side, you can handle these events and create a list of the currently expanded collapsibles, and save this list to the hidden field.  After postback, client code in the pagecreate event can read the list from the hidden field and expand those items.

Assign IDs to all the collapsible divs, then you can save a comma delimited list of IDs to the hidden input:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
    var prevExpanded =  $("#hidden").val().split(',');
    $.each( prevExpanded, function( key, value ) {
          $("#" + value).collapsible( "option", "collapsed", false );
    });

    $( "[data-role=collapsible]" ).on("collapsiblecollapse collapsibleexpand", function( event, ui ) {
             GetAllExpanded();    
    });
});


function GetAllExpanded(){
    var AllExpanded = [];
    $( "[data-role=collapsible]" ).not(".ui-collapsible-collapsed").each(function( index ) {
      AllExpanded.push($(this).prop("id"));
    });
    $("#hidden").val(AllExpanded.join(','));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<asp:hidden>` fields, and on expand change their values. Then you will be able to set the value of `$(".col-md-4").trigger("expand");` on postback.

Answer (score 0):

Well the following works, although I'm still at a loss as to better ways that work on Web Forms and I'll have to find a way to conditionally load this, perhaps using hidden fields as suggested earlier. Thanks for the help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("h2.ui-collapsible-heading").trigger("click");
    });
</script>
```